# Getting HoG features of edited images from HoG features of originals directly

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I had a number of images from which I extracted HoG features and saved them.

I've lost the images now, that was apparently one dataset I hadn't backed up before the machine got messed up.

However I have the files containing the HoG features of those images.

If I had the images now, I would apply shearing and rotation to the images to create more samples, and then take the HoG features of those edited images.

But since I don't have the images... is it possible to somehow work with just the HoG features of the originals in order to get the HoG features of the edited ones?

This is the code I would use to edit the images, if I still had them, from which I would then extract HoG features for object classification:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, io, filter, color, exposure
from skimage.feature import hog
import skimage.transform as tf
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale, rotate, setup, warp, AffineTransform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pickle
import Image

def generateSamples(path, readfile):
    print "generating samples from  " + path+"\\"+readfile
    img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread(path+"\\"+readfile))
    img = resize(img, (50,100))
    filename = os.path.splitext(readfile)[0]
    angles = [3, 0, -3]
    shears = [0.13, 0.0, -0.13]
    i = 0
    no_samples = len(angles) * len(shears)
    samples = np.empty((no_samples, int(img.shape[0]), int(img.shape[1])), dtype=object)
    for myangle in angles:
        myimg = rotate(img, angle=myangle, order=2)
        for myshear in shears:
            afine_tf = tf.AffineTransform(shear=myshear)
            mymyimg = tf.warp(myimg, afine_tf)
            samples[i] = np.array(mymyimg)
            i+=1
            #io.imshow(mymyimg)
            #io.show()  
    newfile = filename + "_samples.vec"
    pickle.dump(samples, file(path+"\\"+newfile,'w'))
    print "saved vec file"
```